# TABLEAU - Calculating measure as a percentage of another measure

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, level-of-detail

I want to calculate a measure as a percentage of another measure. For example, I have a field x_users and I want to calculate the percentage of this field in relation to the total_users. Then, I would like to visualize this percentage set against total_users. I believe I can accomplish this by utilizing dual axis.

Sample dataset

| Date | App | x_users | total_users |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | A | 5 | 10 |
| 2020-01-02 | B | 3 | 15 |

Do you guys have any tips on how to proceed and then visualize this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you please give at least a small amount of sample rows of the dataset?  This can be achieved by `level of detail` functions

Comment: Hi, @AnilGoyal thanks for your response! I've edited my post above.

Comment: So do you want 50% and 20% as output for apps A and B respectively, without any further clause/condition?

Answer (score 0):

For user percentage use this calculation

```
[x_users]/[total_users]
```

**EDIT -- CORRECTION - For correct behavior, use an aggregate calculation as below for ratios such as this**. That will give correct results even when you further aggregate results, say by removing App from the Row shelf.

```
    SUM([x_users]) / SUM([total_users])
```

[image]

For data-visual, a bar-within-bar plot is suggested with labels on `user percentage`,

- dual axis (on x_user)
- synchronise axis
- change width of bar for secondary axis data (x_user)
- unshow header for dual axis
- add labels (on secondary axis data i.e. x_user) for above mentioned calculated field.

[image]

Comment: The original answer will give incorrect results in some cases. An aggregate calculation is more robust for most ratio calculations. I partially edited the answer to note that, but recommend updating the whole answer (and then removing my note). Read about aggregate calculations in the Tableau help for a better explanation. The typical example involves calculating profit ratios